# how to copy one database tables data to another empty database in sql server?

Tags: sql-server

I have one database named `SeoAppDB1` I want to copy all content into another database `seoapp3` using queries.

I need a query to copy tables and data as it is from source db to destination database. How can I do this?

Comment: Do you only want to do this once, or keep the tables in sync?

Comment: no need of sync. just i want to create one database and copy old databse tables on that . @NeilP

Comment: You can run a restore query to restore the database to a different name.  I presume you already have a backup of the source database.

Comment: Do you want copy only content or tables with stucture and content?

Answer (score 1):

as @Dan-Guzman mentioned in his comment, you should use a backup and restore if you have backups available.

You can also use the wizard through SSMS (right click on the database -> Tasks -> Copy Database

Then follow the instructions, select your source and destination servers and set the method you wish to use to copy. Note that you may need to take the database offline or hurt system performance if you keep the database online.

Answer (score 0):

You can use query like this.

```
USE OtherDB;

SELECT *
INTO NewTable
FROM FirstDB.Schemaname.OldTable
```

It will create new table in second database with name NewTable from the oldTable.

Comment: Note that the new table may not be the same schema as the old table, only compatible enough to hold the data. You will also not get constraints copied either.

Comment: this will create one by one table , i need another database with all source database tables @NeilP